# How do I change a <span> class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the span's glyphicon following an action.

Html:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" id="statusButton1" class="btn btn-warning text">
        <span id="iconka" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> На модерации</button>
    <button type="button" id="statusButton2" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="action-1">На модерации</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="action-2">Offline</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="action-3">Online</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="action-4">В архив</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /btn-group -->
```

JS:

```
$("#action-1").click(function(){   
//change class of button
  var className = $('#statusButton1').attr('class'); 
  $('#statusButton1').removeClass(className).addClass('btn btn-warning text');                      $('#statusButton2').removeClass(className).addClass('btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle');

    //change class (icon) of button

    var spanClass = $('#iconka').attr('class');
    $('#iconka').removeClass(spanClass).addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-time'); 

// this not working for span

    alert (spanClass);    

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2472/

In example

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: How change span glyphicon in action?

Comment: Change it to what? In what action, the click? You need to be more clear.

Comment: in example jsfiddle, button has glyphicon, when I change text, I want change icon

Comment: Comment out this block (it's removing the icon!): `$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){...`

Comment: I know, I want change text and icon

Comment: That's the problem dev.nikola - As RC mentioned, you're removing the icon div by calling .html(). so you can't apply a class to it. Here's a workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2475/ There are formatting issues because of whitespace loss, but you can fix that with CSS (or just adding a space in with selText - which is what I did)

Comment: Great! And no problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RC mentioned, you're calling .html(), which is removing both the text node and span element. I updated your fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2475/

The change I made was:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  var selText = $(this).text(),
         icon = $('#iconka').detach(); // REFERENCE TO REAPPEND
  $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.text').html(' ' + selText).prepend(icon);
});
```

The extra whitespace is to address a formatting issue when calling .html(). I would remove whitespace and use CSS to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the text in an element with a class, so you can target it ..

Your current targeting removes the icon as well as the text..

```
<span id="iconka" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
<span class="just-text">На модерации</span>
```

and use

```
$(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.just-text').html(selText);
```

Comment: that is correct answer too